# tqdm dynamic import to work in both notebooks and scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I am trying to import a function which uses tqdm. In some cases I use this function in a notebook and in others I use it in a script. There are these options:

```py
# my_lib.py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm  # option 1
from tqdm import tqdm           # option 2

# some function that uses tqdm
def my_fn():
    for i in tqdm(range(10)):
        pass
```

when I use option 1, it prints weird when the function is called in the script `run.py`.

```py
# run.py
from my_lib import my_fn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_fn()
```

When I use option 2, it prints weird when the function is called in the notebook `test.ipynb`.

```py
# test.ipynb

from my_lib import my_fn
my_fn()
```

How can I use tqdm in this function and have it work correctly in both contexts?

Comment: maybe you should check `__file__` and if it ends with `.py` then import from `tqdm`, and when it ends with `.ipynb` then import from `tqdm.notebook`. But probably you would have to do it inside `my_fn`

Comment: @furas isn't `__file__` the file of the function though? not the import?

Comment: I never test it - so I don't now if it will work and I don't put it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Better late then never.

Just use the following import instead,

```py
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
```

This will automatically choose between `tqdm.notebook` and `tqdm.std`.

Source: https://tqdm.github.io/docs/shortcuts/#tqdmautonotebook